# How to sort numbers in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Sorting ascending a set of numbers sorts them alphanumerical/strings, for example

```
2
11
1
```

gives

```
1
11
2
```

Any extensions or otherwise to sort these as numericals?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look at this extension: [Sort Lines](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Tyriar.sort-lines).  It is written by a vscode team member and has 600k+ installs.

I tested it on your case and the `Sort lines (natural)` command handles numbers as you want.